# How do I select just the first element of a specific class in Bootstrap Tour?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I have many divs with the class `.contact-box` on the page that my Tour is executed on.

I don't want to select all, just the first one.

I tried this:

```
  {
    element: "#page-wrapper div.contact-box:first-of-type",
    title: "Player Info",
    content: "Here we have a quick snapshot of "
  },
```

But that didn't work.

How do I what I want to do?

Comment: Post your whole JS code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all I had to do was just use my instance variable within my view.

I am implementing this within my `profiles#index.html.erb` within a `<script type=text/javascript>` tag, so this is what I did:

```
  {
    element: '#page-wrapper div.contact-box.profile-<%= @profiles.first.id %>',
    title: "Player Info",
    content: "Blah blah blah"
  },
```

That simply chose one of those `contact-box` divs which is what I want.